# C Program to copy integer string using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, pointers, copy

I was trying to  copy integer string to another string. When I try to do so it doesn't show the result. Can you please tell me what mistakes I have made?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr01[50],arr02[50];
    int *ptr01=arr01,*ptr02=arr02;
    int n,i;

    printf("Input array size:");
    scanf("%d",&n);


    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",ptr01);
        ptr01++;
    }



    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        ptr02 = ptr01;
        ptr01++,ptr02++;
    }


    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d",*ptr02);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ptr01++` After the loop, `ptr01` already points to the n-th element so you can't start copying from there.Reset it back to the beginning of the array with `ptr01=arr01`. Next, `ptr02 = ptr01` needs to be `*ptr02 = *ptr01`.

Comment: i did it and still it isn't showing the correct answer

Comment: The last loop also has same problem - `ptr02` already points to n-th element and needs to be reset.

Comment: So what do i have to do?

Comment: Why don't you think about it logically? Surely you can learn something from the comments and work out how to at least progress. I told you that `ptr02` is no longer pointing to the start of the array. So how do you make it point back to the start so that you can start printing from there?

Comment: What the heck is the purpose of the second `for` loop? You've incremented `ptr02` so that it points beyond the end of `arr02`. And `arr02` contains nothing anyway. Why do you even need `arr02`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before this loop

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    ptr02 = ptr01;
    ptr01++,ptr02++;
}
```

you have to reset the value of the pointer `ptr01`. 
For example

```
ptr01 = arr01;
```

And instead of

```
    ptr02 = ptr01;
```

you have to write

```
    *ptr02 = *ptr01;
```

And within this loop

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("%d",*ptr02);
}
```

there is again used a wrong value of the pointer `ptr02` that moreover is not incremented.

You have to write

```
ptr02 = arr02;

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("%d",*ptr02++);
}
```

If you want to deal with pointers then the variable `i` is redundant.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    enum { N = 50 };

    int arr01[N], arr02[N];

    size_t n;

    printf( "Input array size: " );
    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    if ( N < n ) n = N;

    for ( int *ptr01 = arr01; ptr01 != arr01 + n; ++ptr01 )
    {
        scanf( "%d", ptr01 );
    }

    for ( int *ptr01 = arr01, *ptr02 = arr02; ptr01 != arr01 + n; ++ptr01, ++ptr02 )
    {
        *ptr02 = *ptr01;
    }

    for ( int *ptr02 = arr02; ptr02 != arr02 + n; ++ptr02 )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *ptr02 );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Input array size: 5
1    
2
3
4
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Made a few changes, you can try this. I also used comments in the code to explain why i made these changes

```
   #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int arr01[50],arr02[50];

int *ptr01=arr01,*ptr02=arr02;
int n,i;

printf("Input array size:");
scanf("%d",&n);

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    scanf("%d",ptr01);
    ptr01++;
}

ptr01=arr01; //ptr01 points the next element after nth element so we have to reset it to first element

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    *ptr02 = *ptr01;
    ptr01++;
    ptr02++;
}
ptr02 = arr02; //ptr02 points the next element after nth element so we also have to reset it to first element

for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("%d",*ptr02++);
}


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making this a much harder problem than it is. First, you need to lose all the unnecessary stuff like `arr02` and `ptr02`. Try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr01[50];
    int *ptr01=arr01;
    int n,i;

    printf("Input array size:");
    scanf("%d",&n);


    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", ptr01);
        ptr01++;
    }

    ptr01 = arr01;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d",*ptr01);
        ptr01++;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

And I shouldn't need to tell you how bad an idea it is to declare an array of a fixed size and then ask the user how big the array is. What if the user enters 100?